# Testing Web API function in .NET

Tags: .net, performance-testing

Currently I have one .NET project including mobile handheld portion and web services API. Now, I want to test automated testing for web services API functions. How I can do it? Which tools are good to use for web services API testing? Currently I need to insert data from mobile handheld to web services API, I need to test for all the CRUD functions, how I can do it? Anyone can guide me?

Comment: Are you using owin for the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can always unit test your stuff, so I assume you are looking for a good way to integration test your APIs?

I would recommend you to have a look at [RAML](http://raml.org/) which is a way of

- Documenting your API
- Using the documentation to generate a client and use it for automation tests
- Using [Anypoint](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/) you can expose your documentation and get your stakeholders to easily test it as well.

Please have a look at [Design, test and document RESTful APIs using RAML in .NET](http://dusted.codes/design-test-and-document-restful-apis-using-raml-in-dotnet) for a full run through and explanation.